# A property of biholomorphic function on a simply connected space

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose  $X,Y\subsetneq \mathbb{C}$ are domains, $X$ is simply connected, $f :X\rightarrow Y$ is biholomorphic. Can we find a holomorphic function $g: X\rightarrow Y$, for which there exists $\omega\in X$ such that  $f(\omega) = g(\omega)$ and $|g{'}(\omega)|>|f{'}(\omega)|$?

I think the answer is no, but I do not know what properties of the function $f$ or space $X$ to exploit here. I do know that $Y$ is simply connected. Any hints?

Note: I apologize for my poor writing. I made some edits to the text to make it less vague.

Comment: This is far too vague. What is the setting here? Are $X$ and $Y$ complex manifolds? Domains in $\Bbb C$? What does $|f'(x)|$ mean if we're in the general setting? Do you mean there is one point $x$ for which both $f(x)=g(x)$ and $|g'(x)|>|f'(x)|$?

Comment: Surely $g$ is also obligated to take its values in $Y$ or this question isn't interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is smaller than $\Bbb{C}$ then we can [take $h$ some biholomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) from the unit disk to $X$ and sending $0$ to $\omega$.

Then look at $$\phi=h^{-1} \circ f^{-1}\circ g\circ h$$ it sends the unit disk to itself, since $f(\omega)=g(\omega)$ then $\phi(0)=0$,

$\phi(z)/z$ is analytic and $\lim\sup_{|z|\to 1}|\phi(z)/z|=\lim\sup_{|z|\to 1}|\phi(z)|\le 1$, by the maximum modulus principle $|\phi(z)/z|\le 1$ on the whole unit disk, whence $|\phi'(0)|\le 1$ so that $|g'(\omega)|\le |f'(\omega)|$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm a bit confused though. Does this imply that if $\psi : X\rightarrow Y$ is holomorphic and $\psi(x) = f(x)$ then $|\psi{'}(x)| = |f{'}(x)|$, where $x$ is as defined in the statement?

Comment: Biholomorphic. I assume that for some $x\in X$, $f(x)=g(x)$ and the Riemann mapping theorem from which I get $|f'(x)|=|g'(x)|$.

Comment: There lies my confusion. We are given that $f$is biholomorphic and $g$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Moreover, we do not know if $g^{-1}$ exist.

Comment: Ok, wasn't hard to repair.

Comment: Thank you so much!